# How to fix website after reset --hard without undoing it?

Tags: git

I wanted to make git pull but the server say that there is some changes on the file, so make this:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/upgrade87
git pull
```

After that i refresh the website and it is gone, this is the error message: *This site can’t be reached. www.mywebsite.com’s server IP address could not be found.*

I do not want to undo this reset because i have no need to do this, or recover files, i just want to make the website running again, all files are good when take a look with ftp, the changes are applied so i just want to know what damaged the website or how .git directory files can make the domain not reachable.

Can you please help how to fix this ? Thank you!

Best regards

Masmoudi

Comment: I cannot see a connection between git and website. You need to provide more details.

Comment: Thiq problem just happened when i make a git hard reset, i can provide a screenshot if you like, how can i do it here ?

Comment: No need for a screenshot. You need to explain what git has something todo with actual website. For me it sound more like a DNS problem, rather than git.

Comment: @MohamedMasmoudi, if the hard reset changed, moved, or removed certain important files your site might have gone down. You haven't told us what technologies you're using so it's hard to give an example. Aside from that, no Git command should take down your website and there's no way we can help without more information. Where is it hosted? On what operating system? Using what web server? Etc.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the reply, the localconfiguration file relative to the typo3 system was gone, the server admin say that the reset has changed them or erased. He fixed it by himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server admin have found that the configuration files has been removed because they wasn't on git. this is the information that i get, he fixed them again, and added the database connection again.

Thanks for all of you!